# Visual Basic query (excel)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I just started a new job and am trying to use VBA within excel to store values within a multidimensional array.

so I first want to search through a column for values and as they occur, i want to store them once, and assign a product number that will increment each time it encounters a new unique String value in the column. then just print the number to the cell and only change it as it increments/

the values will be Strings, (product styles). the product number will be a number.(int)

will it be possible to do this in VBA for excel. I read online you can't use different data types in the same array.

sorry new to VBA and any help would be great. if i would be better off to use a normal function in excel let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare you array as Variant and then you can store different types in the Array. For example

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    
    ReDim arr(0 To 1)
    
    arr(0) = "hi"
    arr(1) = 1
    
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        Debug.Print arr(i)
        Debug.Print VarType(arr(i))
    Next
End Sub
```

This prints in the immediate window the following

```
hi
 8 ' This corresponds to the type String
 1 
 2 ' This corresponds to the type Integer
```

**EDIT**

As per the question, yes you can have different types of arrays as entries in an Variant-Array. For example:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim str_a(3) As String
    Dim lng_a(8) As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = LBound(str_a, 1) To UBound(str_a, 1)
        str_a(i) = "hi " & i
    Next
    
    For i = LBound(lng_a, 1) To UBound(lng_a, 1)
        lng_a(i) = i
    Next
    
    ReDim arr(0 To 1)
    
    arr(0) = str_a
    arr(1) = lng_a
    
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        Debug.Print VarType(arr(i))
        
        For j = LBound(arr(i), 1) To UBound(arr(i), 1)
            'Do Stuff with the arrays
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

This prints

```
8200 
8195
```

An array always has the `VarType` 8192 + the value of type. For example `String` has the Value of 8, therefore an array of Type String has 8200 (8192+8).

Comment: can i have a multidimensional array with [String][integer] ?